# Distribution Function is Uniform

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading a theorem that is as follows:

(a) If $U ∼ U(0, 1)$, then $F^{−1}(U) ∼ F$

(b) If F is continuous and $X ∼ F$, then $F(X) ∼ U(0, 1$).

I don't understand the meaning of part (b). Is it stating that every continuous distribution function is uniform? What's the difference between $F$ and $F(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

$F$ is a CDF; it is a [deterministic] function.

$X$ is a random variable whose CDF is $F$.

$F(X)$ is the result of plugging in the **random quantity** $X$ into the function $F$. Since $X$ is random, $F(X)$ is also a random variable. Part (b) is stating that the random variable obtained by plugging in a random variable into its own CDF is always a uniform random variable.